How to add additional symbols to indicator names in trading view?
enter image description here
I use the tradingview library for my project but I can't find any option that helps me insert the icon into the indicator's name like in the illustration.enter image description here
I want to insert icons like "new" or "update".
How to add additional symbols to indicator names in trading view?
